# finding python module pynput in apt under linux

Tags: python, linux

I want to use the pynput module for a python project and wanted to install it via apt on my linuxsystem. But I can't find it there. Tried also to look for it with `apt search`.
Does someone know under which name I can find it there? (In General: How to find aliases of pip python packages comfortably in apt?)
I don't want to install it via `sudo pip`, as I have read several times by now that this is not recommended.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `sudo pip` is not recommended , however you can still use `pip` without sudo to install packages safely

Comment: Hey Rishabh, thank your for your quick response. I need to run the skript under root and there modules installed with pip are not found where as modules installed with apt are.

Comment: export the pip path by editing your .bashrc or just edit `$PATH` of your system  to include the pip directory from anywhere in system.

Comment: Hello, you don't need elevated privileges to install anything with `pip` or `pip3`. That said you can install `pynput` with `pip install pynput` or `pip3 install pynput` depending on your version of python without worries. For your other question - the `apt search` is the correct way of searching for available packages.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your support. As found out -that it is not included in the repositories of my dekstop (see below). I'll try it with pip.

Answer (score 0):

Found out in an other forum that there is a website to check if the module is included in the repositories you want to load from:
https://repology.org/project/python:pynput/versions
(In my case I have to go with pip as the pynput module is not included in the repo of my desktop)